# NHibernate 3.0 beta1 Bidirectional One-To-Many Cannot Add Child Object

Tags: .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-many, nhibernate-3

In short, the problem is that, when add child object to the collection property of the parent object **without explicit setting the parent property** of the child object, the insert will fail. Let's take a example:

**NOTE**: I'm using NHibernate 3.0 beta1.

**Example: Product-Category Senario:**

**(1) Database Schema:**

1. Category (Id, Name)
2. Product (Id, Name, Price, CategoryId)

**(2) C# Code for Domain Models**

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; private set; }
}    

public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**(3) Mappings**

```
<class name="Category" table="Category">
  <id name="Id" column="Id">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <bag name="Products" inverse="true" cascade="all">
    <key column="CategoryId" />
    <one-to-many class="Core.Product"/>
  </bag>
</class>

<class name="Product" table="Product">
  <id name="Id" column="Id">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>

  <property name="Name" />
  <property name="Price" />
  <many-to-one name="Category" column="CategoryId" />
</class>
```

**(4) Calling Code**

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    Category category = session.Query<Category>().FirstOrDefault();
    Product product = new Product
    {
        Name = "test",
        Price = 50
    };
    category.Products.Add(product);
    // Here, the p.Category is null, but it should NOT be null
    // And if now I commit the changes the the database,
    // And exception will be thrown: Cann't insert null to column CategoryId
}
```

When the `category.Products.Add(product)` is executed, the `product.Category` shoule be object `category`! If I explicit set the `product.Category` to category, the commit operation will succeed.
Why this? The bug of NHibernate 3.0 beta1 or others?

Comment: NH 3.0 Beta 1 was released? It wasn't announced on nhibernate-development...

Comment: Yes. Look here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaves exactly as documented.

[6.4. One-To-Many Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-onetomany)

NHibernate will NOT set `product.Category` for you. The usual way to avoid forgetting this is adding an `AddProduct` method to category which adds the product to the Products collection and sets the Category property.

Comment: That's too bad. I think Entity Framework did a better job on this point. BTW: I don't find the sentences in the document that says NHibernate will not set the product.Category, can you please copy the sentences for me, thanks :)